# How can I set up a query to compare all columns in a table with my text

Tags: php, mysql, select

I want to create a query where I can compare all columns in a table with my text and get the results. Something like this,

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `column1` LIKE '%text%', `column2`LIKE '%text%', `column3` LIKE '%text%' ......`columnN` LIKE '%text%'
```

Helps are appreciated.

Comment: May I suggest [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)?

Comment: did you want LIKE instead of = ?

Comment: oh ya. sorry..thats LIKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html):

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON table_name (column1, column2, column3, ... columnN);

SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE MATCH(column1, column2, column3, ... columnN) AGAINST ('text')
```

This is not only easier to code, but [it can run hundreds of times faster](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql) than using wildcard patterns `LIKE '%text%'`.

Note you *must* list the same columns in your MATCH() clause as the columns you specified for the index.

Another suggestion: if the multiple columns (column1, etc.) are really multiple values for the same type of thing, you should put them in a child table.

---

Re your questions about getting errors:

My apologies, my example above was incomplete.  `CREATE INDEX` requires that you give the index a name.  For example:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ftbeer ON beer (beer, brewery, style, type, aroma, 
  taste, strength, appearance, origin, rating, price, description);
```

Also if you use back-ticks, be careful to use them properly, to delimit table names or column names.  You seem to have imbalanced back-ticks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My columns are like `id` , `category`, `manufacturer` `type` . They all are distinct. So you are saying that  I should CREATE FULL INDEX ON table_name before I use the that 2nd step there?

Comment: Right, like any other index, you create it once, and subsequently it can benefit many queries.

Comment: I tried it, its giving me an error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON beer (`beer`, `brewery`, `style`, `type`,`aroma`, `taste`, `strength`, `app' at line 1`. Are you sure its CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON table_name and not CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX index_name ON table_name?

Comment: this is the whole error `SQL error during query of CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON `beer` (`beer`, `brewery`, `style`, `type`,`aroma`, `taste`, `strength`, `appearance`, `origin`, `rating`, `price`,` description`);: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON `beer` (`beer`, `brewery`, `style`, `type`,`aroma`, `taste`, `strength`, `app' at line 1`

Comment: Thank you for your edit. However, now I am getting another error `SQL error during query of SELECT * FROM beer WHERE MATCH(beer, brewery, style, type, country, description) AGAINST (): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1` . When I use `AGAINST ('$q')` it gives me an `is not a column` error and when I use `AGAINST ($q)` it gives me the above error

Comment: Its a very new and strange concept coz it doesn't work with integers and at the same time it gets listed below the primary key of  my table on phpMyAdmin. I don't know how this operates to filter my search results.

Comment: Well I'm sorry if it isn't clear.  There's too much information to cover in a Stack Overflow post, so all I can do is suggest you read the documentation on using [FULLTEXT indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html)